# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a web page that display open street map and gets data from SQL server database by long and lat coordinates
i use asp.net mvc    and give me this wrong

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined**   

  where i bind data from database by javascript

**Model**
this model data i create  GetMap() that return data from database by Json function

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetMap()
        {
            var data1 =(from p in db.Map
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Latitude = p.Latitude,
                        Logitude = p.Logitude,
                        Location = p.Location,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        Id = p.Id
                    }).ToList().Select(res => new Map
                    {
                        Name = res.Name,
                        Latitude = res.Latitude,
                        Logitude = res.Logitude,
                        Location = res.Location,
                        Description = res.Description,
                        Id = res.Id


                    });
            return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
</pre>
```

**view file**
view file that display map and return data by Json function

```
    <div id="mapid" style="height:600px"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([31.291340, 34.244190], 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);





            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Maps/GetMap',
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = JSON.stringify(data);

                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {

                        var popup =
                            '<b>Name:</b> ' + data[i].Name +
                         '<br/><b>Latitude:</b> ' + data[i].Latitude +
                           '<br/><b>Longitude:</b> ' + data[i].Logitude +
                        '<br/><b>Location:</b> ' + data[i].Location;


                        L.marker([data[i].Latitude, data[i].Logitude])
                            .bindPopup(popup)
                           .addTo(map); 

                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr) {

                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    alert("Error has occurred..");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Check the for loop in your success function, iterating up to `result.length` but `result` should be `data`.  The error message indicates that some `data[i]` is undefined.

Comment: try $.parseJSON(); also check what you get for data

Comment: What's happening in your linq query though? You can remove the `Select` part after the `.ToList()`. And, if those are the only properties in the `Map` object, you might as well get rid of the entire query and just do `return Json(db.Map.ToList())`

Comment: It is working for you my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in these lines:

```
 var result = JSON.stringify(data);
 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
```

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript `object` to `json` text and `stores` it in a **string**.

**You don't need to iterate a json string** because you need to iterate a `collection`.

You have to iterate `data` directly.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {}
```

The response of the **POST** method is parsed automatically by ajax success **callback**.

Also, you do not need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` property when you're doing a POST request. This is required only for GET verb because it protects you against a very specific attack involving `JSON` requests.

Comment: Yes, you can iterate a string! `s = "abc"; for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { console.log(s[i])}`

Comment: @jpaugh, i updated to `json string`. to be more specified.

Comment: Thanks! I can see you've found the right problem, but look more closely: the OP is trying to reference `data[i]` inside the loop, not `result[i]`. The loop does not need to use `result` at all!

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai well i guess still you can...only diff would be you would be getting extra "". 
   var s ="test";
var s1 = JSON.stringify(s);
for(var i =0;i<s1.length;i++){console.log(s1[i]);}

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a string here

```
var result = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Then looping until the string length, which is the number of characters in this string ( not your json array length)

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) { }
```

**The string length will be more than your json array length.**

So simply fix your loop to use correct variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

}
```

Also there is no need to call `Json.stringify`. simply loop through the json array.

Alternatively, you may use `$.each`

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data,function(indx,item)
  {
    console.log(item.Name);
  }
}
```

Also your server code could be simplifed. There is no need to do the projection twice.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMap()
{
        var data1 =db.Map.Select(res => new Map
                              {
                                Name = res.Name,
                                Latitude = res.Latitude,
                                Logitude = res.Logitude,
                                Location = res.Location,
                                Description = res.Description,
                                Id = res.Id
                             }).ToList();
    return Json(data1);
}
```

You do not need to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` when your action method is decorated with `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to reference a field (Name) which does not exist on a given object (`undefined`). There are three places in your code which reference a Name field:

- `p.Name`
- `res.Name`
- `data[i].Name`

So one of `p`, `res` or `data[i]` is undefined at the moment that you try to reference the `Name` property.